# How do I get Git Bash (on Windows) to automatically connect to "winpty python.exe" upon loading?

Tags: python, bash, git

I'm a newbie, so no laughter at or mocking of me for any illiteracy I exhibit please!

I am able to get Python to work already in Git Bash, but to do so I have to input the following command every time I open Git Bash before I can enter interactive mode.

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'
```

It is tedious to have to do this every time I log into the command line. How do I ensure that Git Bash performs this function automatically upon logging on?

Answer (score 1):

Start "Git Bash" then execute something like the following to modify your user's `.bashrc`:

```
$ echo 'alias python="winpty python.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then exit "Git Bash" and start it again.  You'll see something like this:

[image: Restarted Git Bash]

Now run `alias` and you should see this:

```
$ alias
alias python ='winpy python.exe'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
```

Comment: I tried your first step, then exited Git Bash and opened it again. But it just opens as normal; I did not see the text you said should appear.