# Permission denied problem using pip3 install command

Tags: python-3.x, pip, git-bash, permission-denied

I'm new to Github and I tried using Sherlock, installing the requirements with the code

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But it says `permission denied`, so I tried turning off UAC and opening `git bash` as admin and using the `--user` command but it still doesn't work.

I am using Windows 10 and I see:

[image: git bash error]

Comment: Give this post a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows#:~:text=Try%20to%20give%20permission%20to,It%20works%20for%20me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first that [python3 won't work in minTTY environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536173/6309)

So try instead:

```
winpty python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can set [an alias as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54964151/6309) in your `~/.bashrc`